# Matlab : Turning a script with symbolic variables into a function

Tags: matlab

I am building a double pendulum simulation . 
Now i have written a script with symbolic variables and parameters. I want to turn the script into a function using input value for some of the symbolic parameters. i ve used the command matlabFunction(''), but it didnt work.

Comment: What did not work? Please give an example to understand your problem!

Comment: How does `matlabFunction` not work?  It's specifically designed to convert symbolic formulas into numerical anonymous functions!

Comment: Excuse me for my vague description.  When i am using matlabFunction to convert the script into a function, the console will say : Attempt to execute SCRIPT testMatlabFunction as a function:
/home/ellipidoo/Schreibtisch/HiWi/Isys_Ordner/Matlab/MyStuff/testMatlabFunction.m . However nothing happens after that

Comment: To avoid downvotes, next time **include what you did so far**. Not just some vague description, but the actual contents of `testMatlabFunction.m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always include a default function header in a matlab function. After this header, you can put all your other things.

```
function someOutput = testMatlabFunction(someInput)
    g=matlabFunction(whateverSyntaxYouWereUsing)
    someOutput = g(someInput)
```